# Specific Date Format in mysql

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL

Table

```
ID Date

001 2010-05-01
002 2010-06-08
```

Query

```
Select ID, Date from table;
```

I want to display a date in a specific format

Expected Output

```
ID Date

001 01-Mar-2010
002 08-June-2010
```

How to make a query in mysql.

Need Query Help

Comment: I think you have misspelled "May" in your expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with the format string '%d-%M-%Y'.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(ID varchar(100), Date datetime);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
('001', '2010-05-01'),
('002', '2010-06-08');

SELECT ID, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%M-%Y') FROM table1;
```

Result:

```
ID    Date
001   01-May-2010
002   08-June-2010
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT ID, DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%d-%M-%Y') FROM table;
```

You can find other date formatting options for MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

use `DATE_FORMAT()` in mysql

look at the link for all format option:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format