# Format YYYYMMDD date to text on SQL Select

Tags: mysql, sql, function, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specific Date Format in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412735/specific-date-format-in-mysql)

`select date from table` returns 20111010

what `select FORMATFUNC(????, date,?) from table` returns October 10, 2011?

mysql but there has to be sum dum standard right

Answer (score 4):

You need [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Syntax:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-10-10 19:46:00', '%M %d, %Y');
```

Comment: +1 Looks good.  Although, you might want to also add a comma between `%d` and `%Y`: http://www.sqlize.com/QW8R1tq3c9

Comment: You're right, I over-read the comma in the question. I just added it in my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

its probably something like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%M %d, %Y');
```

and if you need more options read this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format